# Reorganising a lot of methods built on the prototype chain

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've started to write some code to implement a simple game in JavaScript. The basic idea is that dealer.game holds a bunch of objects (player,hand,funds etc) which hold the current state of the game. Then I have various methods which manipulate these objects. I've chosen to use the prototype chain as there could be multiple instances of the dealer.game instance so I wanted shared methods between these instances.

working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BhPrQ/

and the code:

```
dealer = {}

dealer.game = function() {

    this.player = {};

    this.hand = {};

    this.set = {};

    this.funds = {};

    this._drawBoard();

};

dealer.game.prototype._drawBoard = function() {
     //draw board in svg here 
};


dealer.game.prototype.addPlayer = function(name,funds) {
    this.setFunds(name,funds);
    this._drawPlayer(name);
};

dealer.game.prototype._drawPlayer = function(name) {
    this.player[name] = '';
};

dealer.game.prototype._getPlayer = function(name) {
    this.player[name] = '';
};

dealer.game.prototype.setFunds = function(name,funds) {
     this.funds[name] = funds;
};

dealer.game.prototype.removeFunds = function() {

};

dealer.game.prototype.drawFunds = function() {

};




var poker = new dealer.game();
poker.addPlayer("jenny",200);
poker.addPlayer("jack",100);
console.log(poker.player);
console.log(poker.funds);
```

The problem I'm seeing straight away is with even this minimal boilerplate of code adding methods to the object via the prototype chain is going to become messy. I've got a bunch of methods that do stuff to the player and then more that do stuff to the funds...as this grows I can see that I'm going to end up with a huge amount of methods directly linked off the prototype chain which are all mixed in terms of what they do. I know there's technically nothing wrong with this but Is there are better way to organise this? I considered separate objects that require instantiation...something like:

```
dealer.funds = function() {

};

dealer.funds.prototype.addFunds = function() {

};
```

But the problem with this is that the instantiated funds object will no longer have access to the core player,hand,set or funds objects contained within player.game.

How do I reorganise this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face. Create separate classes for the separate parts of my application:

```
dealer = {};

dealer.game = function() {

    this.player = {};

};


dealer.game.prototype.addPlayer = function(name,funds) {

   //assign the object returned by dealer.player to my game.player object 
   //this way my application always has access to all players that have been created 
   this.player[name] = new dealer.player();
};

dealer.player = function() {
   //do some stuff and then return the object
   return this;
};
```